# MATLAB: trained linear SVM assigns all elements of the test set to only one class

Tags: matlab, svm

I have around 1200 examples of classes 1, and -1. 
Each of these examples are represented by a feature vector which has 100 dimensions.

I use cross validation to train and evaluate the SVM. I use the SVM's default settings. 
Now in a 10-fold cross validation, the SVM assigns all elements of the test set into class -1, for some of the folds (3 or 4 out of 10).

As the result, for these folds, tp and fp are always 0, and therefore precision and recall can not be calculated.

I have increased the number of iterations and the SVM obviously merges because I don't get any error.

What causes this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the input data.  Things to check include: are the examples in rows or columns & what does the classifier expect? What does the SVM model look like (i.e. support vectors, linear weights, etc.), if it is empty that's a clear sign that the input is dud. How balanced are your classes?

Comment: The examples are in rows. The data is sparse that means for each feature vector representation most of the dimensions are 0. Almost the same proportion of -1 and +1 classes exist in each fold.

Comment: What SVM implementation are you using?

Comment: maybe your data is not separable linearly, try other kernels.

Comment: I'm using matlab built-in SVM, if that's what you mean Alan. I have tried quadratic and polynomial kernels. Quadratic improve the situation but it still misses 2 folds out of 10.  Polynomial kernel makes the situation worse.

Comment: @Meghi how many positive and negative examples do you have for training at each fold?

Comment: For training set (19 folds), class -1: 710 (65.3%) and class 1: 378 (34.7%). For test set (1 fold), class -1: 37 (64.9%) and class 1: 20 (35.1%).